# how to set JS var from val passed in from the view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Passing a value to the view with @Model.LayerName
Would like to store this value in a JS variable...

```
var g_tableName = @Model.LayerName;
```

the semi colan at the the end of LayerName; is flagging as syntax error but I cant figure out why...any ideas? ta

Answer (score 2):

It's because, I'm assuming, `Model.LayerName` is a string. So when it renders as part of the Javascript it is not being wrapped inside quotations, so whatever your layer name is, it will print directly into the code. For example, if your layer name property value is `this is my layer name`:

```
var g_tableName = this is my layer name;
```

Which obviously isn't valid Javascript. So you'll need to wrap it in quotations:

```
var g_tableName = '@Model.LayerName';
```

Which would result in the following being rendered:

```
var g_tableName = 'this is my layer name';
```

Comment: @John No worries at all